# Can't pass data out of foreach in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

How can I export the data when I open a foreach in the application I developed in Laravel. For example, I want to filter after some id sync.

Blade/View

```
@foreach ($parts as $item)
    @foreach ($country->getPerson ?? [] as $person)
        @if ($country->id == $person->country_id)
        @endif
    @endforeach
    @if ($loop->iteration == $person->part_id)
        @continue
    @endif
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
        <div class="service-item my-3">
            <div class="service-wrapper m-0 bg-white">
                <div class="service-content mt-3">
                    <h5 class="mb-3"> {{ $item->name }}</h5>
                    <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs- target="#service1"
                       href="#" class="text-primary">
                        Alert!
                        <i class="fas fa-angle-right ms-2"> </i>
                    </a>
                    <br> <br>
                    <form class="call-to-action-form m-auto" action="{{ route('add.person') }}"
                          enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                   placeholder="Adınız Soyadınız" required> <br>
                            <input type="text" class="form- control" name="email"
                                   placeholder="E-Mail Adresiniz" required>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="country_id" value="{{ $country->id }}" required>
                        <input type="hidden" name="part_id" value="{{ $item->part_id }}" required>
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Cüzü Al
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

I want to return it here.

what I want to do is

> {{person->part_id}}

```
      by assigning its value outside the foreach

         @if ($loop->iteration == $person->part_id)
            @continue
        @endif
```

My associated models run regularly. Now I need to filter the ids corresponding to my person table in my part table. The code sequence I shared above only takes the latest id. I cannot get other corresponding ids, so it only filters once.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of error you getting, but if you having issue with undefined variable you could try this `person['part_id']`

Comment: I don't know if it works in blade, but in php `continue 2;`  > *continue accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many levels of enclosing loops it should skip to the end of.* https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

Comment: I solved the problem
Thank you very much for your interest :)